# Differences in type inferences in ghci for two functions

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, ghci

I am having trouble understanding the differences in type inferences ghci makes in the example given below. Namely it seems that

- In `func1` the value `listToUse` is inferred to be of type `listToUse :: [Integer] = _`
- In `func2` the values `listToUse` and `val` are inferred to be types `listToUse :: [a] = _` and `val :: [a] = _` respectively.

The code is :

```
module Main where

mylist = 2:[3..]

func1 lst = 
  let listToUse = lst
  in listToUse          -- line 7

func2 lst = 
  let listToUse = lst
      val = 1:listToUse
  in val                -- line 12

main = do
  print $ take 4 $ func1 mylist
  print $ take 4 $ func2 mylist
```

We can see the inferences by putting breakpoints and stepping through the debugger in the manner shown below :

```
*Main> :t mylist
mylist :: [Integer]
*Main> :break 7
Breakpoint 0 activated at Test.hs:7:6-14
*Main> :break 12
Breakpoint 1 activated at Test.hs:12:6-8
*Main> main
Stopped at Test.hs:7:6-14
_result :: [Integer] = _
listToUse :: [Integer] = _
[Test.hs:7:6-14] *Main> :continue 
[2,3,4,5]
Stopped at Test.hs:12:6-8
_result :: [a] = _
val :: [a] = _
[Test.hs:12:6-8] *Main> :step
Stopped at Test.hs:11:13-23
_result :: [a] = _
listToUse :: [a] = _
```

Comment: Probably another example of the dread Monomorphism Restriction.

Comment: When stopped at 12, make a few `:step`s and see what happens.

Comment: @n.m. Hi following what you suggested it seems that initially `listToUse :: [a] = _` and `_result :: [a] = _` but in the final inference `_result :: [Integer] = _`. So I guess the inference starts off with the return value and works its way backwards to the inputs. Thanks.